# Mapper not initialized in Asp.Net Core 2 test project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, automapper, xunit

I have created a test project for my Asp.Net Core 2 app.
Here's my test:

```
[Fact]
public void GetBlogs()
{
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>();
    builder.UseInMemoryDatabase();

    var options = builder.Options;

    using (var context = new Context(options))
    {
        //add new objects (removed for example)

        context.AddRange(blogs);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var context = new Context(options))
    {
        var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelMappingProfile());
            cfg.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile());
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var repository = new BlogRepository(context, mapper);

        var blogs = repository.GetBlogs();

        TODO: Add Asserts
    }
}
```

Here's my GetBlogs method:

```
public IEnumerable<GetBlogsQuery> GetBlogs()
{
    //UpdateBlogsAsync();
    CheckInactiveBlogs();
    return _context.Blogs.Where(x => x.IsActive).ProjectTo<GetBlogsQuery>();
}
```

and the contructor of BlogRepository class:

```
public BlogRepository(Context context, IMapper mapper)
{
    _context = context;
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

But then the test try to invoke ProjectTo I get an error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Mapper not initialized. Call
>   Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use
>   mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do
>   not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're
>   using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you
>   pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.'

Could you please tell what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Update:
Here's my Automapper config class:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration RegisterMappings()
    {
        return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelMappingProfile());
            cfg.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: *if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance*

Comment: Not sure why you're giving me a down vote here? I'm trying to help you. Care to explain?

Comment: Just noticed that you deleted comment you put on the answer? "But then how can I pass object to the BlogRepository constructor?" and explained to you what you can do.. what's the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not provide an instance of `MapperConfiguration` as a parameter on the  `ProjectTo` Extension in which case you do not then you have to use the Static API to Initialization Automapper.

You need to initialize Automapper like the following:

```
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelMappingProfile());
        cfg.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile());
    });
```

The documentation for ProjectTo: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#parameterization

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you're using the instance IMapper for in BlogRepository but you can instead pass IConfigurationProvider and then use that to pass to `ProjectTo` - `IConfigurationProvider config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()); cfg.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile()); });`